# мета-модели не создаются по orm.xml на java 11

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, java-11

Суть проблемы в том что на 11 java мета-модели не строятся при сборке проекта по xml файлу orm.xml(пробовал на 8 java-все ок).использую hibernate-jpamodelgen 5.4.4.Final,так же пробовал другие версии.с применением аннотаций все ок,но нужно использовать xml mapping[image: пустая папка после install maven]

Comment: И какая ошибка?

Comment: ошибки нет,они просто не создаются при компиляции